# What is the best way to stop a user from resizing the top-level window of an application written in WPF?

Tags: wpf, resize, size

What is the best way to stop a user from resizing the top-level window of an application written in WPF?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You will want to use the [`ResizeMode.NoResize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resizemode.aspx) on the window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
</Window>
```

Comment: note that this can also be done using the properties window

Comment: However, if the Window starts off maximised, and you drag it down by the title bar, the window will still resize itself to a "restored" state.

Answer (score 9):

A WPF quirk to note is that if `ResizeMode="NoResize"` and `WindowStyle="None"` you will lose the chrome around the *entirely* in Vista Aero.